# Strange scatterplot of sin(x) in python3

Tags: python-3.x, trigonometry

When trying to do a plot of a sine function between -360 and 360 I came across a strange scatter plot output which looked pretty funky. Does anyone know what it could be? Is it effectively an approximation of the sin graph by the scatterplot or is it something else?

my code is below:

```
from sympy import sin, cos, pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sin_values = []
cos_values = []

for value in range((-360),(360)):
    sin_values.append(sin(value))
    #cos_values.append(cos(value))

plt.scatter((range(-360,360)),sin_values)
#plt.scatter((range(-360,360)),cos_values,color="r")
plt.show()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI6RM.png

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to calculate numerical values you should use `numpy` instead of `sympy`. `Sympy` is made for symbolic calculus whereas `numpy` is for numerical calculation (what you are doing). You could do the array in one shot with that:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,100)
sin_values = np.sin(x)
```

Second, note that usually these functions are expecting [radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), and not degrees. In your case that is a lot of radians, and so you are seeing [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) because your x resolution is not enough to properly resolve the wave. You can convert these degrees to radians by multiplying them by 2pi and dividing by 360. Or construct your `x` array on a better range.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your help! Quick question about numpy: I thought numpy didnt return sin(2*pi)=0 due to pi not being a floating point number?

Comment: pi is considered floating point in numpy, but it is true that because of numerical approximations you might not get exactly 0, but something very small, like 1e-14. `Numpy` is definitively more adapted to want to do. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it! In that case you can consider accept the answer in order to help other people who might encounter the same problem.